# Windows 10 upgrade listed as "insider preview"

Tags: windows, windows-10-preview, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I reserved my windows 10 upgrade using the system tray popup. Now, windows update shows the windows 10 insider preview is available for download. Is that the full version/release of windows 10, or truly just the latest version of the discontinued insider previews?

[image: http://prntscr.com/7zffel]

Comment: I require some information to provide you the correct information..  Do you have [this update installed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035583)?  What version of Windows are you running exactly?

Comment: Sorry for being a little vague. I'm running windows 7 home premium. I do have that update installed.

Comment: The screenshot does not seem accurate.  You have pending updates.  Can you provide what is contained with the window "check your upgrade status"?

Comment: If you have the "Get Windows 10" icon still visible, and even if you don't it likely will work, you can run the command `wuauclt.exe /updatenow` to get a window that will walk you through getting the update.  You might also have to delete the existing hidden directory, which contains the Windows 10 files, check their date the folder should have recently been modified in the last 48 hours.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Windows 10 Insider Preview is not the full version/release of Windows 10. The insider preview is pre-release of product, you can see more information about this program here: https://insider.windows.com/

Comment: Thanks mate! Any idea when they will release the full version? I had the insider preview installed at one point but reverted later.

Comment: **This answer is not 100% correct.**  The Insider Preview actually is the full version of Windows 10.  Microsoft has plans to continue the program through the lifespan of Windows 10 ( in other words for the next 10 years at least ). Your link even says that.